# Xbar Control chart with only sample means

Tags: charts, controls, mean, minitab

i'm trying to create an Xbar R control chart with only the information of the means of each sample and the information of the R.As follows in the next picture.

[image: data]

Anyone know how can i do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually, I Well, actually, I Well, actually, I